# Why is this the exact amount of liquid on plane?

Tags: air-travel, klm

My friend recently flew with KLM and got a 86 ml water bottle and 187 ml of wine. Why those numbers? I couldn't find a reasonable conversion...

Comment: A bottle of wine is usually 750 ml so that's a quarter-bottle. But is this a question about travel? It's like asking why they showed a particular movie.

Comment: Technically the wine bottle should have been 187.5 ml which is a quarter bottle, also known as a piccolo. No idea about the water though as that is not an obvious fraction of a litre.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel, although asking about the size an airline's beverage service container. However, it may be pure physics: how many will fit on a beverage cart and how many are required for each flight, and how much weight do they contribute when full.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of googling, I just visited the [manufacturer web site](http://www.decantae.co.uk/plastic-range/) and it seems like te container was designed and then measured to get te right amount printed on. 100 containers with box is exactly 10 kg now.

[image: What the manufacturer says.]

Comment: I think it is the other way around, they wanted a water cup that fits in the coffee cups they hand out at some meals. Since then they use it at all flights where water is served as standard.